# Find Cathetus C1, C2 Knowing Hipotenuse or Find C1, C2, C3, C4 of Rectangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, rectangles

I have a rectangle. I know all sides and 4 points for it (see black rectangle below). I resize one edge of this rectangle to any point (see resized red color rectangle and new point B).

[image]

Here is the question. I can calculate the distance between A and B so they are known and center of this rectangle is known too (x,y). How to calculate catheti based on this?

(If this is not enough for solution, please tell me what else should be known to calculate sides)

Comment: In your picture you resize both dimensions of the black rectangle, not just one edge. In this case, you can up with any red rectangle and knowing the length of its diagonal won't be enough information to figure out the lengths of its sides.

Comment: I see. Knowing everything about initial rectangle (black) what can I use to calculate additional values to help solve this problem? Please note that A point is never changing in its coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $A=(0,0)$ and that the original black rectangle is aligned with the coordinate system.

Then the dimensions of the new red rectangle are $2|x|$ and $2|y|$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this rectangle is rotated and is NOT aligned with coordinate system. However, I can still know all points of this rotated rectangle. Point B can be anything user decides so there is no way to tell relations between catheti.

Comment: @Vad What is the coordinate system that you are measuring the coordinates $(x,y)$ in?

Comment: It's a standard coordinate system but this rectangle can be rotated in my program so I cannot rely on it. However, I can calculate points A and B as on photo and center. I may calculate angles too. Will that help, perhaps?